# How to get specific entries in Contentful

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, contentful, contentful-api

So I want to know how I can get all the entries where my sessionId equals to (for example: 4).

[image: 1]

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? session)
    {

        var cardio = await _client.GetEntries<CardioModel>();
        
        // ContentfulCollection<CardioModel> cardioModels = new ContentfulCollection<CardioModel>();

        // foreach (var model in cardio)
        // {
        //     if(model.Session == 4){
        //         cardioModels.add(model)
        //     }
        // }

        return View(cardio);
    }
```

I tried this but the .add isn't a thing, I tried various ways but none of them is working and I can't find good docs about what I want. I thought probably something with `.getEntriesRaw()` but I don't know how to work with that.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? session)
    {
        var cardio = await _client.GetEntries<CardioModel>();
        
        // ContentfulCollection<CardioModel> cardioModels = new ContentfulCollection<CardioModel>();

        // foreach (var model in cardio)
        // {
        //     if(model.Session == 4){
        //         cardioModels.add(model)
        //     }
        // }

        return View(cardio);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just modifying just a little bit

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? session)
    {
        if (session == null || session != 4) return View(null);

        var cardio = await _client.GetEntries<CardioModel>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Session == 4);
        
        return View(cardio);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! In the meantime I got it working with a little workaround. 

 public async Task<IActionResult> Week1()
        {
            var cardio = await _client.GetEntries<CardioModel>();

            List<CardioModel> cardioModels = new List<CardioModel>();

            foreach (var model in cardio){
                if(model.Session == 1){
                    cardioModels.Add(model);
                }
            }
            return View(cardioModels.ToArray());
        }